# How Do I Get Browser Viewport Width & Height In Javascript And Apply To CSS ID's?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, return-value

Is there a way to get the realtime `width` and `height` values using Javascript and apply them to a number of `div id`'s? I want to build a site that has 5 sections that are always `width: 100vw` and `height: 100vh`. Only one section can be seen at a time as each section has a `#` anchor and vertical scrolling is disabled.

The problem I'm having is when I resize the browser window, the CSS doesn't keep up and must be refreshed for new values for the section `width` and `height`. I'm wondering if there is a way for Javascript to constantly monitor the browser `width` and `height` and apply those values to a set of `id`'s.

**Example**

The browser window is 1000px by 500px so the `id #one, #two` now have a `width: 1000px` and `height: 500px` and when the browser is resized to 1200px by 600px the values for `#one , #two` would be set as `width: 1200px` and `height: 600px` in the CSS.

Here is my **[codepen](http://codepen.io/mtthwbckmn/pen/zhBEb)**.

Comment: You should look into the `resize` event.  In jQuery, `$(window).on('resize', function () {  /* recalculate sizes here */ });`

Answer (score 3):

As @gary-storey already said, use the resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
   var curWinWidth  = $(window).width();
   var curWinHeight = $(window).height();
   // do stuff here
});
```

Answer (score 0):

i've done this for my own page, that way:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    <!-- get viewport size//set content size -->
    var currentViewPortHeight = $( window ).height();
    var currentViewPortWidth = $( window ).width(); 
    $("#mainFrame").css({ "height" : currentViewPortHeight, "width" : currentViewPortWidth });
    $("#mainFrame").resize();   
};
```

you may set a timeout interval though - since this event fires very often during a windo resize - especially if the user uses drag&drop. according to my stackoverflow studies, the best would be a 300ms timeout, to get a smooth resize transition, and not firing it to often...

Comment: of course - you have to change the #mainframe selector to match you own div id or class